# Formula Field, Checkbox Based on Income & Rent Cost

Tags: formula-field, admin, checkbox

Forgive if this is a silly question, but I've been staring at this formula field for hours and I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong. I'm trying to create this formula field checkbox based on rent & income that marks as true when the rent consists of over 30% of the income, but less than 50%. (E.g., Income: 100,000 Rent: 32,000 -> True;
Income: 100,000 Rent: 68,000 -> False). Here's are two different versions of the formula I've tried to write.

```
OR(
    AND(Household_Annual_Income__c > 0, Pays_in_Rent__c/Household_Annual_Income__c >= 0.3,  Pays_in_Rent__c/Household_Annual_Income__c < 0.5),
    AND(Household_Annual_Income__c = 0, Pays_in_Rent__c > 0)
)
```

And the second version/try:

```
IF(
    AND(Household_Annual_Income__c > 0, Pays_in_Rent__c/Household_Annual_Income__c >= 0.3,  Pays_in_Rent__c/Household_Annual_Income__c < 0.5), 
    True, 
    IF(
        AND(Household_Annual_Income__c == 0, Pays_in_Rent__c > 0), 
        True, 
        False 
    )
)
```

For both of my attempted formulas, they're working as expected EXCEPT for when the income is at zero and the rent is greater than zero. In the case that income is zero, I also would like the checkbox to be True. Anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: I imagine that your attempts are running into an issue trying to divide by zero. You should try making the `AND(Household_Annual_Income__c == 0, Pays_in_Rent__c > 0)` bit be evaluated first, before you try to do any division by `Household_Annual_Income__c `. Salesforce does have "short-circuit evaluation", so checking for 0 first should mean your formula will never actually try to divide by 0.